# Laravel Many to Many Form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a problem ...I try to save to a database some data.
This is the situation:

[image: Relations]
I have some cavi (cables) ...for make a cable I need some Semilavorati (samifinished). For make a semifinished I need some mp (raw material).
The relations are many to many because a cables can have many semifinished and a semifinished can belongs to many cables. The same is for semifinished and raw material.

I have 3 Model (Cable - Semifinished - Material) with the relative relations and the withPivot for the quantity.

My problem is how build a form for save all together. Someone have some tips?

I have thinks to a select2 for the cables (so I can do a choice). The problem is how select more semifinished with quantity. And how select more material with quantity ...all in the same form.

...maybe with a form repetear?

Thanks to all for eventually help!

Comment: art started a html form or you just figure out how to do it. if not as I understood you need to select a cable with one or more semi fished and each semi fished has one or more material and you need to store all at once !!

Comment: Correct.  I need to create a Form for that like this example: http://demolive.iwebstudios.it/Esempio.jpg  Step1 Select a cable  Step 2 Select more finished with their quantity  Step 3 for each semifinished assign the raw material with their quantity.